# Can unary_function of STL of C++ (as implemented in gcc 4.7.x) have a virtual function?

Tags: c++, stl, unary-function

`binder2nd` is derived from `unary_function`.

The following code snippet does not work:

```
greater<int> g;

    //greater is derived from binary_function

//bind2nd returns binder2nd object and binder2nd is derived from unary_function

const unary_function<int,bool> &greater_than_0 = bind2nd(g, 0);

    // base class reference type holding reference to derived class object

remove_if(lst.begin(), lst.end(), greater_than_0);
    //does not work
```

Whereas the following code snippet works:

```
greater<int> g;

const binder2nd< greater<int> > &greater_than_0 = bind2nd(g, 0);

remove_if(lst.begin(), lst.end(), greater_than_0);
```

Will it be helpful to have a dummy virtual function in `unary_function` so that the first code snippet works. Can that improve the usage of STL?

Comment: These functions are deprecated for a generic [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: I think you want `std::function`, it is polymorphic

Comment: Not sure how a virtual function would help here... actually I am thinking that you might not even be referring to `virtual` at all, but rather a different overload?

Answer (score 2):

`unary_function` is a convenience type that adds a couple of typedefs to your derived class. It is **not** polymorphic; if you write code that mentions it by name other than as a base class in a class definition you've almost certainly made a mistake.

Comment: This answer sums up the problem. I'd like to throw in two more comments: If the baseclass doesn't have virtual functions, anyone using a reference to this class will not see any virtual functions either. You can not inject these into existing classes in C++. Secondly, the functors passed around STL code are copied! Even if unary_function had a virtual function, it would be sliced off by the copying. Remember: Templates use compile-time polymorphism, a.k.a. duck typing.